# Eclipse wont recognize my HTC desire

Tags: android, eclipse, windows-7, adb, htc-android

I'm trying to use my HTC Desire as a test phone for my Android application, but Eclipse just can't see it, now If i go to device manager there is a yellow !, i click uninstall, re-connect my HTC phone to the computer and it can not install the drivers, can anyone help me fix this problem? I really need to be able to use my HTC phone as a test device.

Canvas

Comment: The device manager should give an error telling you whats wrong. What is the message?

Comment: Do you install it with the Google Drivers provided with the SDK?

Comment: Either try with google drivers of sdk or install htc sync that worked for me

Comment: are you using `windows 8`?

Comment: Windows 7, im trying this link out now http://jamesgiang.wordpress.com/2010/04/25/adb-drivers-for-htc-desire/

Comment: have you enabled **USB Debugging** on your device?

Comment: Is USB debugging on your Desire flagged?

Comment: Sometimes incompatible drivers are on your system and have to be removed first. I blogged about this here: http://neatocode.tumblr.com/post/41025880563/nuke-from-orbit-usb-installation

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I always had the same trouble with HTC phones and some Samsung phones as well even when using the official driver.

I found if you install PDANet http://pdanet.co/ this installs the driver for you and it always seems to work. You don't actually need the software afterwards and can be uninstalled, but it successfully installs the driver and device is detected.

Answer (score 0):

Installing HTC Sync Manager on Windows 8.1 resolved my problems with HTC Desire 600.You can download it from here: 
http://www.htc.com/www/support/software/htc-sync-manager.aspx

 Details brought from here:
http://grindheadgames.com/htc-desire-showing-adb-devices-fix/

**Important Note:** I also noticed there is a checkbox in USB Settings called **'HTC Sync Manager'**. You should check it to enable '**USB Debugging**'. Otherwise although you have enabled usb debugging in 'application development' section, USB Debugging will not work.